# Сравнить два словаря и записать результат в третий

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, словари, множества

помогите, пожалуйста)

Даны 2 словаря: англо-русский и англо-немецкий. Сгенерировать из них русско-
немецкий словарь. Если связь слов отсутствует(есть в одном словаре, но нет в другом), то
запись в новый словарь не вносить.

Например:

```
dict1 = {'ape': 'обезьяна',
         'bat': 'летучая мышь',
         'cat': 'кот',
         'donkey': 'осёл'}

dict2 = {'ape': 'affe',  
         'bat': 'schläger',
         'cat': 'katze',
         'boy': 'junge'}

dict3 = {'ape': 'affe'}
```

и т.д, а слова, которые не совпадают по словарям - не были включены в третий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код для русско-немецкого словаря

```
dict1 =  {'ape': 'обезьяна', 'bat': 'летучая мышь', 'donkey': 'осёл'}
dict2 = {'ape': 'affe', 'bat': 'schläger', 'boy': 'junge'}

dict3 = {}

for i in dict1.keys():
    try:
        dict3[dict1[i]] = dict2[i]
    except:
        continue

print(dict3)
```

У вас просто в примере dict3 это англо-немецкий словарь

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться словарным сокращением и пересечением множеств ключей этих словарей:

```
dict1 = {'ape': 'обезьяна',
         'bat': 'летучая мышь',
         'cat': 'кот',
         'donkey': 'осёл'}

dict2 = {'ape': 'affe',  
         'bat': 'schläger',
         'cat': 'katze',
         'boy': 'junge'}

dict3 = {dict1[key]: dict2[key] for key in set(dict1) & set(dict2)}
```

Результат в `dict3`:

```
{'обезьяна': 'affe',
 'кот': 'katze',
 'летучая мышь': 'schläger'}
```